# Finding the potential energy of a conservative force

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

[image]

My solution to show whether each of the forces is conservative is to check whether $\textrm{curl}\, \vec {F}$ is zero. It is $0$ if conservative and not $0$ if not conservative, which I have no problem with. But how can one find the potential energies of $\vec{F}$ from that relationship? I don't really have a clue, and any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I like the answers you are getting, but don't some of them have the sign wrong?  $\vec{F}=-\partial U / \partial{ \vec{r}}$ is what we use in physics.

Comment: @LouisB i think you are correct with that yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the line integral $\int_{\mathbf{a}}^{\mathbf{x}} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$, where $\mathbf{a}$ is an arbitrary point. If $F$ is conservative, this is well-defined and has the right derivative (gradient), by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for line integrals, and hence it is $U$, up to a constant.

For example, the first one is conservative, and the integral can be computed as
$$ U(X,Y,Z) = \int_{0}^{(X,Y,Z)} x \, dx + 2y \, dy + 3z \, dz = \frac{1}{2}(X^2-0) + (Y^2-0) + \frac{3}{2}(Z^2-0). $$
The second one is also conservative, and $x\frac{dy}{dt} + y\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}(xy), $
so the potential is $U(X,Y,Z)=XY$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\bf F$ is conservative, it has some potential $U$, that is, a function for which ${\bf F} = -\nabla U$. Writing this equation in components gives thesystem
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
F_x &=& -\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\\
F_y &=& -\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}\\
F_z &=& -\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
of partial differential equations. Finding a potential amounts to solving this system.

So, for example, for the field $\bf F$ in (a), the system is
$$-\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = x, \qquad -\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} = 2 y, \qquad -\frac{\partial U}{\partial z} = 3 z .$$
Integrating the first equation gives that $U$ must have the form
$$U(x, y, z) = -\frac{1}{2} x^2 + A(y, z)$$
for some $A(y, z)$, and likewise integrating the second and third equations give respectively that $U$ can also be written as
$$U(x, y, z) = -y^2 + B(x, z) = -\frac{3}{2} z^2 + C(x, y) .$$
Putting these forms together gives that $f$ has the form
$$U(x, y, z) = -\frac{1}{2} x^2 - y^2 - \frac{3}{2} z^2 + K$$
for some constant $K$. We can check that all such functions are solutions, by the way, simply by computing $-\nabla U$ and checking that it coincides with the given $\bf F$.

Comment: should $${\bf F} = \nabla U$$  be$$={\bf F} = -\nabla U$$

Comment: @Gibberish This is a matter of convention. The *scalar potential* of a vector field $\bf F$ is a function that satisfies the first equation (with no minus sign), but when the vector field represents a force usually a negative is used, so that a the force pushes the object from a higher potential to a lower potential. I've changed the signs in my answer for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, if ${\bf F} = (y,x,0)$, then ${\bf F} = \nabla f$ where $f_x(x,y,z) = y$,  $f_y(x,y,z) = x$, and $f_z(x,y,z) = 0$. Now, an antiderivative of $f_x(x,y,z)$ *with respect to $x$* is $xy$, an antiderivative of $f_y(x,y,z)$ *with respect to $y$* is $xy$, and an antiderivative of $f_z(x,y,z)$ *with respect to $z$* is $0$.  Adding together all *unique* terms of those antiderivatives gives us that $f(x,y,z) = xy + C$ where $C = 0$ in this case since $f(0,0,0) = 0$ by assumption. (Here I used $f$ instead of $U$; sorry).

Comment: May I ask why is it not $2xy$?

Comment: @Gibberish First, confirm that $2xy$ would give you the wrong answer by calculating $\nabla f$. The reason is that from $f_x(x,y,z) = y$, you know that $f(x,y,z) = xy + C_1(y,z)$; from $f_y(x,y,z) = x$, you know that $f(x,y,z) = xy + C_2(x,z)$; and from $f_z(x,y,a) = 0$, you know that $f(x,y,z) = 0 + C_3(x,y)$. Comparing these three expressions for $f$, you arrive at the realization that $f(x,y,z) = xy + C$ for some constant $C$.